# Count read bytes in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I read from file in main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::ifstream in ("file.txt");
    std::string str;
    in >> str;
    in.close();
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    sleep(100);
}
```

State of /proc/[pid]/io before running:

```
rchar: 11179
wchar: 18
syscr: 15
syscw: 2
read_bytes: 0
write_bytes: 0
cancelled_write_bytes: 0
```

But read_bytes value in io of process didn't change after reading. Why?

Comment: By "io file of process" I assume you mean `/proc/PID/io`?

Comment: Yes, /proc/[pid]/io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man proc`, under `/proc/[pid]/io`:

> `read_bytes`: bytes read.   Attempt  to  count the number of bytes which this process really did cause to be
> fetched from the storage layer.  This is accurate for block-backed filesystems.

As I interpret this, if your file was already cached in memory, then reading it will not cause the `read_bytes` number to increase.

You could try and drop the cache first with `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.  Then I suspect that when you run your program again, you will see a nonzero number in `read_bytes`.  Note that since reads from storage are done as full blocks (typically 4K bytes), you will see multiples of the block size in this number, even if your file was smaller than that.

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.rst?h=v5.9.1 another source for that doc

Comment: indeed the value is non-zero, equal to 5554176, but all I thought was "ProcessID = 1", why is it so big?

Comment: Wait, are you looking at /proc/[pid]/io for your process, or for PID 1?  Either way, note that this will count the disk reads needed to load the program's binary and any shared libraries that were not already in cache, as well as any other files read by the C library initialization routines.  You could use `strace` to see everything that's being done.